# Callstack error when using map() to render images in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, base64, jsx

I'm trying to render a list of images in my React application by using the map() function to iterate over an array of objects containing image data in base64 format. However, I'm encountering a call stack error when trying to render the images.

Here's the code snippet I'm using:

```
data.map((el) => {
  const base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(el.img.data)));
  console.log(el.img.data);
  return <img src={`data:image/png;base64,${base64String}`} />;
});
```

The data array contains objects with the following structure:

```
{
  id: 1,
  img: {
    data: /* base64 image data */
  }
}
```

Comment: What **exactly** is the error? And why are you calling `.map()` and not saving the result?

Comment: Also, what is the point of making a `Uint8Array` from the base64 image data?